# Images won't load in Pygame but there's no error in the Python IDLE

Tags: python, image, pygame

None of my images will load in pygame, no matter what I do. I have tried doing the images with the absolute path with both forward and backward slashes. In pygame the screen just loads and doesn't give me any errors but the image doesn't either load.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))

BGImage = pygame.image.load('Plat.jpg')
window.blit(BGImage(0,0))

Eggshell = (240,235,220)

vel = 15
x = 3
y = 450
width = 50
height= 60




isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run == False


    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and x  > vel:
        x-= vel
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 920 :
        x+=vel
    if not (isJump):
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1

        else:
        isJump = False
        jumpCount = 10


    window.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(window,Eggshell,(x,y,width,height))
    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You have to blit the image in the while loop after `window.fill((0,0,0))`: `window.blit(BGImage, (0,0))`. Please try that and then tell me if it works or if there's another error.

Comment: OH MY GOD!!!  Thank you for the help that totally worked skrx, I spent 2 days trying to find out why it wouln't load. Your a life savior skrx, I'll add you in my WILL later in life.

Answer (score 0):

You need to blit images/`pygame.Surface`s onto the display surface after you clear it with the `fill` method. If the `BGImage` covers the whole screen, it's not necessary to fill the screen before you blit the image.

```
window.fill((0, 0, 0))
window.blit(BGImage, (0, 0))  # Blit the image at the top left coords (0, 0).
```

---

I also recommend converting the image with the [`convert`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) method (or `convert_alpha` if the image has transparent parts) because that will improve the blit performance drastically.

```
BGImage = pygame.image.load('Plat.jpg').convert()
```